# iOS: ViewController kept by reference

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I have a viewcontroller A where I add views of other viewcontrollers dynamicaller to A's subView. For efficiency reason I keep those viewcontrollers in a dictionary and remove/add their views dynamically.

However A gets deinitialized but not the other viewcontrollers. I also see this in memory debugger but do not know how to solve this cycle.

[image: retain cycle]

Here is my dictionary inside A that holds all subview controllers:

```
private var subControllerMap = [String:UIViewController?]()
```

And here how I do that dynamic loading

```
 func addControllerWithIdentifierAndZoneId(_ identifier: String, storyboardNibName: String, containerView: UIView,zoneId: String?){
        containerView.subviews.first?.removeFromSuperview()
        let _ = children.map{$0.removeFromParent()}
        var ctrlr: UIViewController? = subControllerMap[identifier] as? UIViewController

        //only create a new controller if needed - otherwise use reference from map
        if ctrlr == nil{
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardNibName, bundle: nil)
            ctrlr = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier)
            subControllerMap[identifier] = ctrlr
        }
        guard let controller = ctrlr else{
            return
        }

        if let castedController  = controller as? BController {
            castedController.isInEditMode = true
        }else if let castedControler = controller as? CController{
            castedControler.isInEditMode = false
        }else if let castedController = controller as? DController{
            castedController.isInEditMode = true
        }

        controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addChild(controller)
        addSubview(subView: controller.view, toView: containerView)
        controller.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
```

This function is called if I tap a segment on a segmented control. E.g.

```
addControllerWithIdentifierAndZoneId("BController", storyboardNibName: "Room", containerView: containerView,zoneId: zoneId)
```

I tried to clean up in vieDidDisappear, but it did not help

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

    subControllerMap.values.forEach { (controller) in
        controller?.view.removeFromSuperview()
        controller?.removeFromParent()
    }
    subControllerMap.removeAll()
    containerView.subviews.forEach { (view) in
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    containerView.removeFromSuperview()

}
```

Comment: While the code helps provide some of the picture, the class structure would help in understanding the `memory cycle`. Could you provide a bit more detail (particularly the class where `subControllerMap` is defined and its relation to the `addControllerWithIdentifierAndZoneId` method)? Also, have you tried making it a `weak var`?

Comment: Thanks for the update. Could you also share the code where you are calling `addControllerWithIdentifierAndZoneId` method?

Comment: You're not really providing the necessary information. Memory cycles are detected by identifying intertwined properties. Providing code snippets without sufficient context would not help determine the cause of the memory cycle. For instance, who holds the reference to the segmented control that in turn calls `addControllerWithIdentifierAndZoneId`? Is there a scenario where you might be calling this method with the source controller? As I said, without context, it would be a long shot for anyone to figure out the cause. Best of luck :)

Comment: my hope was that you can point me into the right direction with the CFDictionary. I do not see the problem there. The other references I use are all weak

Comment: I can't see any noteworthy issues with the provided code. The only thing I can see is the dictionary itself being a `non weak` variable. Another thing you can try is moving the code from `viewDidDisappear` to `viewWillDisappear` but I'm not sure if either of these solutions would work since I cannot work out the cause of the memory cycle

Comment: @netshark1000 This does indeed look strange. Could you check if your dictionary is being released please? Try subclassing it and add a destructor method just printing something out. If it is not released then start checking where all is it referenced. It might be some closure persistent somewhere or something...

Comment: 'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not '[String : UIViewController?]' is what I get if I set subControllerMap as weak

Comment: Of course. I completely forgot that Dictionaries and Arrays are treated as `structs` so they are not reference types. My bad

Comment: and they can not be subclassed

Comment: It doesn't look like any of your code would be causing the retain cycles. You're sure that the `deinit` methods of those VCs aren't being called? I find that the most likely culprit in Swift is closures with strong references to `self`.

Comment: @netshark1000 - Try creating a [mcve] ... that will allow others to look at and experiment with the actual code.

Comment: @netshark1000 You are correct, dictionaries are copied, not retained. If you are sure that the view controller is deallocating then so is the dictionary. But there might be another copy of it existing somewhere. Are you referencing it anywhere? Sending it to any other object maybe? Is your issue gone if you don't use the cache? You can test that simply by commenting out a line `subControllerMap[identifier] = ctrlr`.